# Prompt File Save as Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project in which i have some data in JSON. Their is a save button to save JSON data into a file and download it. All is working fine. I want to know is their any way to open file save dialog box so user can save file with desired name and location in local machine. I tried/searched a lot but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by all browsers, but you can convert your JSON to a data uri and set it as the href attribute of an anchor element

```
<a href="data:application/json; YOUR JSON DATA HERE" download="yourfilename.json">Save</a>
```